# created repository method is returning wrong output like packagename.classname.table (com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users@6a3258a4)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new lerner of spring boot, i am creating a project after inserting user data into database when i am fetching data from table using method "User findByEmail(String email) it should return user object but it returning something like "com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users@5e2f219c".
All the codes are mentioned below

1. this is entity class

```
package com.blogconduitapi.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean isEnabled;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String name, String email, String password, boolean isEnabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

2. this is controller

```
package com.blogconduitapi.controller;

import com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users;
import com.blogconduitapi.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody Users users) {
        Users existingUsers1 = userService.findUser(users.getEmail());
        users.setEnabled(true);
        userService.createUser(users);
        return "user save successfully";
    }


}
```

3. this is UserService

```
package com.blogconduitapi.service;

import com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users;

public interface UserService {

    Users findUser(String email);

    void createUser(Users users);
}
```

4. this is repository

```
package com.blogconduitapi.repository;

import com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
Users findByEmail(String email);



}
```

5.this is serviceImpl

```
package com.blogconduitapi.service.impl;

import com.blogconduitapi.entity.Users;
import com.blogconduitapi.exception.UserDefinedException;
import com.blogconduitapi.repository.UserRepository;
import com.blogconduitapi.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public Users findUser(String email) {
        Users users = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        System.out.println("{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}} " + users);
        if (users != null) throw new UserDefinedException("mail already exist");
        return users;
    }
    @Override
    public void createUser(Users users) {
        if (users.getName().isEmpty() || users.getEmail().isEmpty() || users.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            throw new UserDefinedException("There are some required fields are missing");
        }
        userRepository.save(users);
    }
}
```

6. application.property

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/apidb

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

7.this is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>blogconduitapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>blogconduitapi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is working it's just the issue with print. Override toString() method in your User class and try printing the user again. Java has no idea how to convert your User to string and print it in format you would like otherwise.